# What is the remainder when $2^{2^{517}}$ divided by $23$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is the remainder when $2^{2^{517}}$ divided by $23$?
I tried Fermat Little theorem, and seems like I cannot make a further step. The trick here is about $2^{517}$ which does not follow the normal principles of power's calculation.

Comment: You and presumably your classmates have already asked this exact question multiple times over the past few days.  Please, work together in groups or at least use the search functionality of the website.  It was also asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699068/how-to-solve-22517-mod-23) for those users who can view deleted questions.

Comment: [The search functionality at work for this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=2^{2^{517}}).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You want to compute $2^{2^{517}} \pmod{23}$. By Fermat $2^{22} \equiv 1 \pmod{23}$. So you need to work on the exponent $2^{517}$ modulo $22$.

Observe that
$$2^{517} \equiv r \pmod{22} \implies  \begin{align*}2^{517} & \equiv r \pmod{2}\\ 2^{517} & \equiv r \pmod{11}\end{align*}$$

Now try solving the right hand system.